# SSIS Only inserting data if Error Output set to Redirect Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

Got a weird problem.

I have created an SSIS package that imports data via an ODBC connection between an External database and SQL Server 2008.

The Data Flow has a Source Query (simple: select columns from table).

Data Conversion to String [DT_STR]

Destination: SQL Server table with same structure.

If I execute the Task, 11,000+ rows are entered. There are No errors.

However, the data is all White Space and NULLS, except the Date fields are correct (which is how I can tell that it's trying to enter the right data).

If I change the Error Output on *any* single column in the Source Query to **Redirect**, all of the fields are populated correctly. If I set it to Ignore or Failure, we get the blanks.

I added a Flat File Destination and connected the Redirect row, and nothing is written to it.

We have several packages like this, and I've never had this problem.

I also recreated the entire Package, and the same thing happens.

Any ideas?

There are 8 Data Flow tasks doing the same thing in this package for different databases. If, I can't figure it out, is there a good way to set the Error Output to Nowhere?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2/26/18:**
I added Data Viewers, and on the first Viewer from the Source, I get the Blanks/NULLS if the Error Output on the Source is NOT set to Redirect Rows.  If I set to Redirect, the Viewer shows data.  NOTE: I can set ANY column Error Output to Redirect on the Error column OR the Truncation column. As long as one is selected, the data from the Source comes through.

Since this is the Viewer between the Source and Data Conversion, doesn't that mean the problem would be at the Source Query and NOT the Data Conversion?

Here it is with Source Query - Error Output set to default **Fail Component**
[image]

Here I set to **Redirect**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: where are you redirecting the error outputs ??

Comment: Several ways to debug. 1) Check the intermittent data with data-viewer. 2) Use `multicast` for error re-direct (though this solution is not advisable). Btw what ll happen if you use OLEDB source instead of ODBC ?

Comment: "way to set the Error Output to Nowhere?" You could send it to a script transformation that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I updated the problem after adding Data Viewers. Looks like the Source data changes prior to the Conversion? Thanks for all the assistance so far

Comment: Thanks Prabhat G, good thought, but OLE DB doesn't seem to work with Informix. Using the Data Viewers I've determined that issue appears to be with the ODBC driver. If you make an answer, I'll mark it as such